# How to optimise the following code to read user input?

Tags: scala, optimization

With Scala, how to optimise the following code to read user input? Function must return an array reading every element from keyboard input. In the below snippet, variable `i` is a **dead letter**. How to avoid the dead letter or optimize the below code?

```scala
  def fetchUserInput(n: Int): IndexedSeq[Int] = {
    for {i <- 0.until(n)} yield {
      scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**Source**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source.html) util class.

```
def fetchUserInput(n: Int): List[Int] =
  scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines.take(n).map(_.toInt).toList
```

*You can change the `toList` with any collection you prefer*.

Comment: Is there a way to still use ```for``` without a **dead letter**?

Comment: @dexter2305 Yes, just use an underscore, `for (_ <- 0 until n) yield scala.io.StdIn.readInt()` Or, since you are using the advantage of the **for comprehension**, just call `map` directly: `(0 until n).map(_ => scala.io.StdIn.readInt())`

Comment: Yes. ```_``` used in the map may not be termed as a dead letter anymore but the placeholder defined is no longer used. I am expecting to use range collection but still not define any variable / implicits that may not be used at all.

Comment: @dexter2305 I do not understand. `map` expects a function, a function takes some input, you may say I do not care about the input, that is what `_` means.

Comment: Alright. I get that _ is a wildcard which is ignored and also not defined. I take that.